# How to prove that the map $H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to H^n(M, \mathbb{R})/i(H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})) $ is an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to get the middle isomorphism in eq 3.3 of *'Quadratic functions in geometry, topology, and M-theory* by Hopkins and Singer [(here)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211216) from the mentioned Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

It suffices to prove that  $H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} $ is isomorphic to $ H^n(M, \mathbb{R})/i(H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})) $. (Here $M$ is a manifold.)I am able  construct a map $H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to H^n(M, \mathbb{R})/i(H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})) $ in the obvious way, and check that it is indeed well defined. However I am unable to show that this map is an isomorphism. I would appreciate any clues. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{i}\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$ you get an exact sequence

$$\dots\rightarrow H^n(M)\otimes\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{1\otimes i} H^n(M)\otimes\mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^n(M)\otimes \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$

by tensoring with $H^n(M)$ (integral coefficients are assumed unless otherwise stated). The left-hand map is not in general injective, but this is of no consequence for what we want to prove.

Now there are isomorphisms $H^n(M)\otimes\mathbb{Z}\cong H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^n(M)\otimes\mathbb{R}\cong H^n(M;\mathbb{R})$, which are natural in the second variable, meaning that the map $1\otimes i$ in the exact sequence above becomes the change of coefficients map $i:H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^n(M;\mathbb{R})$. Thus we have exactness of

$$\dots\rightarrow H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})\xrightarrow{i} H^n(M;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^n(M)\otimes \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0,$$

and we may safely identify

$$H^n(M)\otimes\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong H^n(M;\mathbb{R})/i(H^n(M;\mathbb{Z})).$$

Edit: Fixed an embarrassing error pointed out by the op.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion free module. E.g. $[1/2] \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion element (when multiplied by 2, it vanishes). In fact the kernel of the map $i$ is $H^{n-1}(M;\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ which need not vanish

Comment: @user90041, Thank you for pointing out that ridiculous oversight on my part. I've edited the question. The important part was the right-hand epimorphism, and you don't actually need the sequence to be short exact. Also, the kernel of $i$ is the torsion group $Tor_\mathbb{Z}(H^n(M),\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, which is only a (non-natural) summand of $H^{n-1}(M;\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ (the complement being $H^{n-1}(M)\otimes\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: Thank you so much ! Sorry I made an error in my comment (about the kernel of $i$) above, thank you for correcting me. Just two more questions : (a) I am able to see that $Tor_\mathbb{Z}(H^n(M),\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ is a submodule of $H^{n-1}(M,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, but how do we show that it is a summand ? (b) How do we know that $H^n(M)\otimes \mathbb{}R$ is isomorphic to $H^n(M,\mathbb{R})$ ? Had the groups been homology groups, I would have used the Universal coefficient theorem to see the answer to both the questions. However the universal coefficient theorem for cohomolog ...

Comment: ... involves $Ext$ rather than $Tor$. In this particular case, we can use that $M$ is given to be compact, and thus all the homology and cohomology groups are finitely generated in order to prove the statement in (b) but I do not know how to do it in general. Thanks a lot !

Comment: There is another universal coefficient theorem for cohomology involving tor, which gives a split short exact sequence $0\rightarrow H^n(M)\otimes G\rightarrow H^n(M;G)\rightarrow Tor(H^{n+1}(M),G)\rightarrow 0$. There are actually assumptions that either $G$ is finitely generated, or $H_*(M)$ is of finite type. The second of these certainly covers the case of compact $M$. My reference for this is actually tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology", Pr. 11.9.6. (although there are a lot of better texts on homological algebra which cover it).